Early Chinese Martial Arts movie about a Swordsman and the "ultimate" sword technique
In the late 70's I caught a movie with a Chinese friend at the Great Star theater on Jackson Street in San Francisco(sadly, both the theater and the neighboring Jackson Street Cafe where we ate afterwards - her grandfather owned it, are now gone). I have been trying to identify the film ever since. My friend told me at the time that it was considered a Chinese cinema classic.
Storyline: a young swordsman is travelling to challenge other swordsmen; I believe the premise was to find a superior technique to add to his skills, with the ultimate goal of becoming the greatest of all throughout the land. 
He learns of an old retired sword master, who was said to have achieved the "ultimate" technique, but is a secretive recluse. The young swordsman befriends and captures the heart of the old master's daughter(granddaughter?), in the hope of ultimately stealing her father's "secret".
Finally, the young man challenges the older swordsman, so sure in his ability that the old man's only option will be to use(and so reveal) his secret sword fighting technique. As swords are drawn the young sword fighter instantly lands a fatal cut, with the oldster's sword still in its sheath. As the old man lays dying, the young man tragically learns the truth he sought: that the ultimate technique is to transcend violence and never to use one's sword to kill in the first place. Having taken so many lives in countless challenges, the master had retired determined to never take another life. The old master's sword had rested for so long without being used, that the ancient blade had rusted in place, and had become permanently one with the rusted sheath encasing it.
The film had an ultimately sad plot, but I loved the underlying message, and both acting and color cinematography were good. Over time I became convinced that the part of the young swordsman was Ti Lung, and that the title of the film was "The Unbeatable Sword", but I could be way off on both points. Does anyone recognize the film?

Sounds like you're looking for The Sword (Jian) from 1971. From an online synopsis:

Hsia Ho Wei (Wang Yu), who is a talented young nobleman, is obsessed with collecting precious swords, always looking for the greatest sword in the world. Despite all the objections of his mother, he dedicated his life to enlarge his personal sword collection and so his ego. But one day, during a small victory celebration, a White-bearded swordmaker appears and tells Hsia Ho Wei that the best sword in the world is now in the hand of Kuan To (Got Heung-Ting), who lives in mountain tops with his beatiful daugther (Chan Pooi-Ling), secludedly. As soon as he hears this, our hero runs to the place Kuan To lives, and asks him [for] the sword. But Kuan To has bad memories about it, and doesn’t want to give [it]. Then Hsia Ho Wei attempts to steal the sword but this time he meets Kuan To’s superiour kung fu and is heavily wounded. Fortunately, Kuan To’s daughter Ying Erh cures him and some love develops between them.

He finally challenges the old master to a duel and runs him through with his sword, but the master never draws his. The young man then learns that it's the best sword because it has never been drawn in 20 years and had rusted in its sheath. The film is currently on Youtube. Here are some scenes:

